# ssh commands and password requests in a bash script

Tags: bash, ssh, sftp

I am trying to make a script that will sync with another folder over a ssh connection.  What I want to do is sync my local folder with the folder over ssh and then perform an ssh login.  For these two commands I need to enter the same password and it's a little annoying so I am trying to make a script for it to put my password into a temporary variable and pass that variable to the two spots it is requested.  This is what I have.

```
read -s -p "Enter Password: " mypassword && echo "$mypassword" 
| rsync -vz -r `~/Desktop/Market_Maker/Market_Maker XXX@XXX.edu:~/281_Projects 
&& echo | "$mypassword" ssh XXX@XXX.edu`
```

What this ends up doing is gives me 3 password prompts and does not work at all.  What is wrong with the script?

Comment: The easier option would be to use ssh keys and leave out the password thing. You cannot use `echo` to pass passwords into a prompt.

Comment: My school computer prevent ssh keys for security reasons (from what i'm told)

Comment: What you are attempting is a hundred times more insecure and quite likely in violation of your school's security policy as well.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `sshpass` to store your password for a specific login. Once installed you can run the command:

```
sshpass -p 'PASSWORD' ssh XXX@XXXX.edu
```

to login to the server. I think that might be the functionality you are looking for. You might also consider setting the `RSYNC_PASSWORD` variable to be the password in the script.

If you want to avoid storing your password in the script you can prompt for it using:

```
read -s RSYNC_PASSWORD
```

This will store the password for the duration of the scripts execution.

Comment: Well then I would have to store my password in the script, which I would prefer to avoid if I could